# Lambda expression as a Consumer parameter does not work correctly

Tags: java, jpa, lambda

I want to make save and delete methods via JPA. I figured out it would be great to use a general method that executes transaction.

But my code seems to work not as I expected (I think I might make a mistake in Consumer logic?):

```java
class MyClass {
   private EntityManager entityManager;

   MyClass() {
      entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-unit")
                               .createEntityManager();
   }

    public void save(MyObj obj) {
        executeInsideTransaction(entityManager -> entityManager.persist(obj));
    }

    public void delete(MyObj obj) {
        executeInsideTransaction(entityManager -> entityManager.remove(obj));
    }

    private void executeInsideTransaction(Consumer<EntityManager> action) {
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            action.accept(entityManager);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            logger.error("Transaction at MyClass went wrong and was rolled back! {}", e);
        }
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyObj obj = new MyObj();
      MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

      myClass.save(obj); // it does nothing
}
```

It neither throws any exceptions nor persists/removes an object to the database.

Comment: I can't see this being an issue with `Consumer`. Are you positive you're using `EntityManager` correctly?

Comment: Creating of manager is correct because method 'get' works fine in this class. So I suppose the problem is in: lambda expr / Consumer (maybe logic of consumer is incorrect?) / action.accept(entityManager). But I can not find out the concrete spot of the bug

Comment: No, they look fine. That's why I'm suggesting the problem is elsewhere. It's difficult to use a FI like `Consumer` incorrectly.

Comment: Are you really logging the exception to the console? Is it possible that your logger is logging somewhere else? Have you added a breakpoint?

Comment: Ok, I think I found out where it comes from. Just wrong usage of JPA. The problem is that I truly do not use `MyObj obj = new MyObj();`(get one from the database). Instead I use `MyObj myObj = myClass.getById(5);`. And this object has autogenerated primary key so when I try to save it again JPA probably does not create one more row in the database but just literally does nothing. I am going to go into details.
Thank you for your help!